# How to launch MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, timer, sms, messageui

I have this code that runs a 15 second delay timer before it sends an SMS:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(sendMessage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This code goes to a method called waitScreen that displays a view controller with an activity indicator and a label telling the user that the 15 second timer is in place. After the 15 second timer, this view is dismissed (please see code below) and then I want to launch the `MFMessageComposeViewController` view with the user's body and recipient already in place. Due to iOS inability to automatically send SMS, the user have to tap Send for the SMS message to be sent.

This is my sendMessage method:

```
- (void)sendMessage {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
    controller.body = messageField.text;
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:contactNumber.text,nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

}

The `messageField` is a `UITextField` where a user types the SMS message while the contactNumber is the contact's number from the address book.

My question is why is my `MFMessageComposeViewController` not launching? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to add/remove your waitView from/to self.view instead presenting it in modal?..I think the problem is that when you call dismiss on self you're going to release this view..otherwise you have to call dismiss on the waitView not in the view that call it.

Comment: You're reply is a bit vague but I understand snippets of it. Will try that. Thanks Mat!

Comment: Tried it, yet nothing happened. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change your first line to

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Same result if I did that. It just doesn't animate.